# smart contract owner choose to reject or accept a transaction?

Tags: erc-721, multisignature, timelock

How keep transaction the user send and owner accept the transaction ?

NFT will be mint in the game (ERC 721). And I have to give users permission to mint, but because everyone can mint outside the game, the owner needs to check the URI and the values before minting.

if there is a problem with the mint Owner can Cancel the transaction.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How keep transaction the user send and owner accept the transaction with contract for mint

Comment: smart contract owner choose to reject or accept a transaction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a mint request function that stores mint requests and a approve mint for the Owner of the contract only, that way the owner can approve mints or rejects them.

Would look something like this:

```
function requestMint(/*params to take into consideration*/) external {
   mintRequests.push(/*this request param*/);
} 

//The owner will use this to see the mint request pile so far
function checkMintRequest() view onlyOwner returns(/*How you decided to store it*/){
    return mintRequests;
}

function requestMint(uint id) external onlyOwner{
    MintRequest accepted = mintRequests[id];//Im thinking this could be a struct
    mint(accepted.account, accepted.tokenId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the best way to do this is to give a request